# Jade Parser: "Anonymous blocks are not allowed unless they are part of a mixin" Error

Tags: node.js, express, block, pug, anonymous

I've got this error:

> *"Anonymous blocks are not allowed unless they are part of a mixin"*

with this Jade file:

```
html
    body
        style(type='text/css', media='screen')
        div#div_name
            display: block
            height: 300px
```

obviously the problem is with **display: block** - any ideas \ solutions?

Comment: Note `display` and `height` are not html tags. So you can write `#div_name(style="display: block; height: 300px")`

Answer (score 0):

The following Jade

```
style(type='text/css', media='screen')
div#div_name
    display: block
    height: 300px
```

will not compile.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
<div id="div_name">
    <display><block></block></display>
    <height>...... and then you get an error with the 300px
</div>
```

**To include *literal* text, put a period at the end of the element.**

```
style(type='text/css', media='screen')
div#div_name.
    display: block
    height: 300px
```

will compile to:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
<div id="div_name">
    display: block
    height: 300px
</div>
```

Now, I’m guessing that’s probably not what you want.
I’m guessing you want the `div#div_name` literally in your style tag, so you should write the following. Notice how the text is indented, and there’s a period at the end of the `style` element.

```
style(type='text/css', media='screen').
    div#div_name {
        display: block
        height: 300px
    }
```

will compile to:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    div#div_name {
        display: block
        height: 300px
    }
</style>
```

Lastly, don't forget to use semicolons in CSS.