# Anonymous blocks are not allowed unless they are part of a mixin - Jade & Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm working my way through Node.js Essential Training with Joseph LeBlanc on Lynda.com and I seem to have the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137600/jade-parser-anonymous-blocks-are-not-allowed-unless-they-are-part-of-a-mixin), but their solution didn't work for me.

Whenever I navigate to `localhost:3000/list` I get the following error:

`Anonymous blocks are not allowed unless they are part of a mixin.`

**/views/layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
    body
        div.container
            block
```

**/views/list.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    ul
        each employee, index in allEmployees
            - employee = employee.getInfo()
            li= employee.name
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    res.render('list', {
        title: 'All Employees', 
        allEmployees: allEmployees});
};
```

**/app.js**

```
app.get('/list', routes.list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for **/views/layout.jade** you want the following. Note that last line as `block content` over just `block`

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")
    body
        div.container
            block content
```

Comment: Haha I just discovered this less than 30 seconds ago on my own. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: You're welcome. I figured it would be one of those things you'd either catch while re-reading the code or would stare at for hours not noticing. I slap my forehead a lot with those kind of things. :-)